# Embedded case in cursor not producing a variable for update

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, sql-update

SQL Server 2012, I set up my cursor like this:

```
DECLARE @EmployeeID nchar(10)
DECLARE @TotalDaysWorked nchar(10)

DECLARE @GetEmmployeeID CURSOR
SET  @GetEmmployeeID = CURSOR FOR
SELECT [Emp#]
FROM [dbo].[Transform] where Home='ROOMS'
OPEN @GetEmmployeeID
FETCH NEXT
FROM @GetEmmployeeID INTO @EmployeeID  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
```

Cursor starts Running innards

```
SELECT Emp#,
      (
        (CASE WHEN [WK1_Day1] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      + (CASE WHEN [WK1_Day2] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      + (CASE WHEN [WK1_Day3] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      + (CASE WHEN [WK1_Day4] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      + (CASE WHEN [WK1_Day5] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      + (CASE WHEN [WK1_Day6] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      + (CASE WHEN [WK1_Day7] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      )
      AS total_days_worked 
        FROM [dbo].[Transform]
        WHERE [Emp#]=@EmployeeID and [Home] = 'Rooms'   
       --This is what I can't figure out how to do...  the rest works
        --UPDATE 
         --[dbo].[Transform]  
          --Set [Week1DaysWorked] = total_days_worked
         --Get the next record    
FETCH NEXT
FROM @GetEmmployeeID INTO @EmployeeID
END
CLOSE @GetEmmployeeID
DEALLOCATE @GetEmmployeeID
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a `cursor` here.

you can do a Set based `update` instead. Try this.

```
UPDATE 
[dbo].[Transform]  
set [Week1DaysWorked] = (CASE WHEN [WK1_Day1] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      + (CASE WHEN [WK1_Day2] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      + (CASE WHEN [WK1_Day3] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      + (CASE WHEN [WK1_Day4] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      + (CASE WHEN [WK1_Day5] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      + (CASE WHEN [WK1_Day6] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      + (CASE WHEN [WK1_Day7] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
where [Home] = 'Rooms'
```

Comment: Best solution for *most* cursor problems - ***avoid cursors***!